# How to report GCP network issue in us-west2-a

Tags: google-compute-engine

Apologies, if this is a wrong avenue to be asking but being a noob, I'm not sure how I can reach the GCP support team to report intermittent network issues we're facing only on servers hosted in us-west2-a datacenter.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can go to google cloud console and find the [support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) page.

In the support section of the cloud console there are options:

- [Cases](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases)
- Chat Support
- Phone Support
- Community Support

Hope this helps!